# How to read commands from a file and execute them?

Tags: bash

The content of 'cmds.txt' is as follow:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" adamH@K1201.myhost.cn "/usr/bin/whoami"
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" alexB@K1202.myhost.cn "/usr/bin/whoami"
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" adamR@K1203.myhost.cn "/usr/bin/whoami"
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" kevinC@K1204.myhost.cn "/usr/bin/whoami"
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" rajE@K1205.myhost.cn "/usr/bin/whoami"
```

I'm trying to iterate through this file in prompt and execute them respectively. My command is:

```
export IFS=$'\n'; for i in `cat cmds.txt`; do $i; done
```

But it complains **bash: ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" maxK@K1261.myhost.cn "/usr/bin/whoami": No such file or directory**.

Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don't put entire commands in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [don't loop over lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). The simple and straightforward solution is to factor out only those parameters which actually vary.

```
while read user_host; do
    ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "$user_host".myhost.cn /usr/bin/whoami
done <<'____HERE'
    adamH@K1201
    alexB@K1202
    adamR@K1203
    kevinC@K1204
    rajE@K1205
____HERE
```

Comment: Nice perspectives and advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use `source`?

```
source cmds.txt
```

Or even shorter:

```
. cmds.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplest way to achieve what I intend to do. But anyhow, I'm encountering this problem right now, so I'd like to figure it out :]

Answer (score 2):

Since you've set `IFS` to just a newline, when it does word splitting on `$i` it only splits it at newlines, the spaces are no longer treated as delimiters. So the entire line is taken as the command name, not a command followed by arguments.

But if you fix that, it still won't work, because quotes are not processed after expanding a variable. You need to use `eval` to put it through all the rules of command parsing.

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in `cat cmds.txt`; do eval "$i"; done
```

But instead of using `for` and having to set `IFS`, you could do:

```
while read -r i; do eval "$i"; done < cmds.txt
```

Comment: To site:  'quotes are not processed after expanding a variable'. What does it mean?

Comment: The quotes you have around `"StrictHostKeyChecking: no"` will not be parsed to keep that as a single argument. The quotes will be kept in the command literally, and the space will split the argument.

Comment: Another question, what does '-r' means after `read` command? I've `man read`, but could hardly find anything.

Comment: It's in the `bash` man page. It tells it not to treat backslash as an escape character when reading.

Comment: @Jahid In this case `eval` is just doing exactly what `source` would do. I don't know why he doesn't want to use `source` -- maybe he wants to log the commands before each one is executed. But any issues with `eval` would also affect any other method of executing the commands in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Putting commands in variables isn't a good idea, but if you want to do it any way, then you can do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
${line[*]}
done <cmds.txt
```

Note: Don't use quotes in variable `$line` ( `"$line"` or `"${line[*]}"` ). It won't work for this case.

One way to use your existing code while avoiding using `eval` might be:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat cmds.txt`; do #use of $(<cmds.txt) is better than `cat cmds.txt`
bash <<EOF
${i[*]} 
EOF
done
```

Note: using `cat` and `for` to read line from file isn't recommended, use `while` loop instead.